# WCF RIA DOMAIN SERVICES

Tags: wcf-ria-services, wcf-data-services

I created WCF RIA DOMAIN Services project with Silverlight 4 with entiry framework having enablabed WCF RIA . Two projects are created;silverlight and web. Project is running file on my local system. But upon hosting on web server. it shows remote server error. If there any svc file which i have to created or Domain service host it byself.I can find any service reference. is this something i have to add as .svc file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project is working fine locally and not when you deploy to a web server, the first thing to check is if the ServiceModel assemblies are installed in the GAC of the server.  If they are not, then in your project, do the following...

1. In the References folder of Solution Explorer, locate the assemblies called System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.*, right click on each and select 'Properties'
2. In the Property window, set 'Copy Local' to true.

This will place these assemblies in the 'bin' directory.  Then deploy the bin directory to the service.